# Unable to perform click operation on elements with similar xpath styles in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, download

I've a web page with multiple download links(all pdf). I'm using selenium to test them (essentially to download all those pdfs). Given below is a spinet from the code:

```
//here's the list of all the elements   
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[*]/ul/li/div/a[3]")); // total elements found: 278

            for (WebElement we:elements) {
            System.out.println(we.getText());
    //custom written wait method
        waitForElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[*]/ul/li/div/a[3]"),10); //executed 270 times
            we.click(); // only the last item (278th) is actually clicked.

            System.out.println("@click"); // this line is executed 278 times        
            }
```

It works fine, but only downloads the last pdf. Introducing a wait also doesnt work.

Comment: You should probably make use of better and more accurate xpath that help you retrieve the exact required WebElement.

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, can you try it with this css selectors;

```
By.css("div>ul>li>div>a:nth-of-type(3)")
```

Comment: I figured the elements were taking only a couple of seconds to load so I had a put a 10 sec wait-time which apparently didn't work but increasing the wait time to 30 secs made the script work. I'm still clueless as in what made that work but anyway thanks for your answers. By the way, I tried the CSS too but with same results. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing download settings - insert the below snippet before clicking on download links :

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);     
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\test");
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf,application/msword,application/x-rar-compressed,application/octet-stream,application/csv,text/csv,");      
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        driver.get("any site");
```